# Composer custom installer paths with WPackagist

Tags: php, wordpress, composer-php, wpackagist

By default, dependencies from http://wpackagist.org/ install to `/wp-content/plugins` or `/wp-content/themes` to mimic the default locations for WordPress but I've previously been able to specify that dependencies from http://wpackagist.org/ should go in a specific directory with the following:

```
"extra": {
    "installer-paths": {
        "vendor/{$name}/": ["type:wordpress-plugin"],
        "vendor/{$name}/": ["type:wordpress-theme"]
    }
}
```

i.e. to put them in the general `/vendor` directory to be treated as code dependecies. However in a new project this is now not working. Similar searches reveal that the `type` looks for the value set in the dependency's `composer.json` but seeing as WPackagist mirrors the WordPress repository, plugins and themes from WPackagist don't have a `composer.json`.

I tried explicitly stating the `vendor-dir` but it made no difference but interestingly, setting the installer path for each dependency works as expected, e.g.

```
"extra": {
    "installer-paths": {
        "vendor/cmb2/": ["wpackagist-plugin/cmb2"]
    }
}
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is you have two keys with the same name so the second is overwriting the first. Try this instead:

```
"extra": {
    "installer-paths": {
        "vendor/{$name}/": ["type:wordpress-plugin", "type:wordpress-theme"]
    }
}
```